Cannot access variable before initialization in javscript iife
I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Q12' before initialization" inside the changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent function.  Any idea why?  Thanks.


const formController = (function () {
    return {
      'changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent': changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent
    };

    const formScope: any = $("form#userAnswerForm");
    const Q12: any = $('.persistable[id=Q12]', formScope);
    const Q23: any = $('.persistable[id=Q23]', formScope);
    
    function changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent() {
        $('input.persistable, select.persistable').not(Q12) //<---Reference Error
        .each(function () {
            console.log('each persistable input and select listeners (change, mouseout)');
            const thisPersistable: any = $(this);
            const Q12_or_Q23_is_not_empty: boolean = !commonUtility.isEmpty(Q12) && 
            !commonUtility.isEmpty(Q23);
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
})();

$(function(){
    formController.changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent();
});




While functions are hoisted, you still seem to be returning within formController before setting your variables. Thus formScope, Q12, and Q23 wouldn't be set. Perhaps you need to move those declarations within changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent().

Additionally, you seem to be missing some closing parentheses and brackets.

Thank you.  I edited the closing bracket and parentheses.
Yes, I could declare them inside each function in the controller IIFE, but there are many other functions in the controller need the variables.  Thus, I declare them at the beginning of the controller declaration.  How could I avoid repeating the declaration in the functions?  Thanks.

@user266909 You don't need to redeclare the variables in each subfunction. All you need to do is to move the return statement to the bottom of the IIFE.

In short you just have to move declaration before return cause in return you call function that try access Q12 which is declared after return
const formController = (function () {
    const formScope: any = $("form#userAnswerForm");
    const Q12: any = $('.persistable[id=Q12]', formScope);
    const Q23: any = $('.persistable[id=Q23]', formScope);

    return {
      'changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent': changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent
    };
    
    function changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent() {
        $('input.persistable, select.persistable').not(Q12) //<---Reference Error
        .each(function () {
            console.log('each persistable input and select listeners (change, mouseout)');
            const thisPersistable: any = $(this);
            const Q12_or_Q23_is_not_empty: boolean = !commonUtility.isEmpty(Q12) && 
            !commonUtility.isEmpty(Q23);
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
})();

$(function(){
    formController.changeCssClassIfOldAndNewValuesAreDifferent();
});

